# How to display the original URL in the browser in case of forward

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, browser, forward

I have created a web application `MyApp`.

I have a JSP `roleAdd.jsp` which has a form that submit to `RoleAdd.do` URL.

```
<form id="form_role_add" method="post" action="RoleAdd.do">
   <label id="label_role_name">Role Name: </label>
   <input type="text" id="role_name" name="role_name">
   <label id="label_role_desc">Role Desc: </label>
   <input type="text" id="role_desc" name="role_desc">
   <button type="submit" id="button_add" name="button_add">Add</button>
</form>
```

In the `web.xml` I map `RoleAdd.do` URL to `RoleAddServlet` servlet.

```
<servlet>
   <servlet-name>RoleAddServlet</servlet-name>
   <servlet-class>com.myapp.web.servlet.RoleAddServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
   <servlet-name>RoleAddServlet</servlet-name>
   <url-pattern>/RoleAdd.do</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

In the `RoleAddServlet` servlet, I am forwarding back to `roleAdd.jsp`.

```
RequestDispatcher view = request.getRequestDispatcher("roleAdd.jsp");
view.forward(request, response);
```

Now I type in http://localhost:8080/MyApp/roleAdd.jsp in the browser. The JSP is loaded. I put in data in the form and click on Submit button. It went to the `RoleAddServlet` servlet and then forwarded back to `roleAdd.jsp`. Only issue is that the browser is now showing http://localhost:8080/MyApp/RoleAdd.do instead.

Is it possible that the bowser show http://localhost:8080/MyApp/roleAdd.jsp?
If yes then what I need to do?
If not then why?

Thanks

Comment: See if a redirect works instead: `response.sendRedirect("/roleAdd.jsp");`

Comment: It work but I lost my attribute which I have set to request object in `RoleAddServlet` servlet. That attribute is more important than the incorrect URL showing in browser.

Answer (score 0):

Forwards a request from a servlet to another resource (servlet, JSP file, or HTML file) on the server. This method allows one servlet to do preliminary processing of a request and another resource to generate the response. New request object will not be created in request dispatcher. If you want to change URL you must use `request.sendRedirect(String url)`. It does not possible with `forward(ServletRequest request,ServletResponse response)`. If you want to pass parameters with redirect you do following: `YourPageName.jsp?name=nameYouEntered`.
I hope this will help you.

Comment: Hmm interesting to append the parameters to the query string for a redirect.

Answer (score 0):

**Solved the problem by following line :**

```
response.sendRedirect(request.getContextPath()+"/report.jsp");
```

**Note : Do not use below lines of code for redirection.**

```
RequestDispatcher RequetsDispatcherObj1 = request.getRequestDispatcher("/report.jsp");
RequetsDispatcherObj1.forward(request, response);
```